# DomCrawler complex div nesting

Tags: symfony, dom

I'm having trouble trying to get to some data using the dom crawler. 
I want to get the name 'Avocado' and '£1.50'  I though I'd be able to do something like

```
 $message = $crawler->filterXPath('h3')->text(); 



  <div class="product"> 
  <div class="productInner"> 
  <div class="productInfoWrapper"> 
  <div class="productInfo"> 
  <h3> 
  <a href="http://website.com" > 
  Avocado  
  <img src="pic.jpg" alt="" /> 
  </a> 
  </h3> 
  </div> 
  </div> 
 <div class="pricingAndTrolleyOptions"> 
 <div class="pricing"> 
<p class="pricePerUnit"> 
 £1.50<abbr title="per">/</abbr><abbr title="unit"><span                 class="pricePerUnitUnit">unit</span></abbr> 
   </p> 
 <p class="pricePerMeasure">£1.50<abbr 
title="per">/</abbr><abbr 
title="each"><span class="pricePerMeasureMeasure">ea</span></abbr> 
 </p> 
</div> 
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get h3 text:

```
$message = $crawler->filterXPath('//div[@class="productInfo"]/h3')->text();
```

To get price (i.e. for class pricePerMeasure):

```
$price= $crawler->filterXPath('//p[@class="pricePerMeasure"]')->text();
```

Comment: thanks helped me out on something else, previous gave up, dom can be so frustrating

Comment: actually needed to add //h3  $message = $crawler->filterXPath('//div[@class="productInfo"]//h3')->text();